# Auto Calculate datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

How to auto calculate Column in datagridview?

Something like in microsoft excel when you set a formula into a column.

i have a date hired Column and a tenure column. the tenure Column should auto calculate with a `DateHired` - `DateToday` formula.

please help. thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site isn't a code writing service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: If you are or reasonably can use a `DataTable` as the data source then you can simply set the `Expression` property of that `DataColumn`.

Comment: `DateHired - DateToday`? Wouldn't that create a negative date or at least go out of bounds? It's like taking `5 - 20` instead of the probably wanted `20 - 5`.

Comment: no it did not. i already got the formula but the problem is i dont know what to do with the datagridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following statement to calculate years/months/days and many more between two dates.

```
LblDateDiff.Text = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value)
```

You can passed any valid date in place of DateTimePicker1.value & DateTimePicker2.value

You can use another options in place of DateInterval.Year those are as follow.

- Day
- DayOfYear
- Hour
- Minute
- Month
- Quarter
- Second
- Weekday
- WeekOfYear
- Year

To use above function in DataGridView, you can use following code.

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
qry = "select * from TblDate"
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, con)
da.Fill(ds)
If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Days", "Days")
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    With DataGridView1.Rows(i)
        .Cells(1).Value = DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, .Cells(0).Value, Today.Date)
    End With
Next
```

In above example you will get output mentioned in the image with current date as 5/7/2016[image]

[image]

Comment: Where should I put it? i tried to put it in cellendedit handle but it did not work.

Comment: I have added another image that shows the code and result. Don't forget to vote up and mark answer please

Answer (score 0):

You can handel the even `"CellEndEdit"` in your GridView as :

```
   Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("DateHired", "DateHired")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("tenure", "tenure")

    End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
        Try
            Dim order As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

            If IsDate(order("DateHired", e.RowIndex).Value) Then
                'Dim dt As Date = order("DateHired", e.RowIndex).Value
                Dim dt1 As Date = order("DateHired", e.RowIndex).Value
                Dim dt2 As Date = Date.Parse(DateTime.Now)
                ' order("tenure", e.RowIndex).Value = DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, dt, Date.Now)
                order("tenure", e.RowIndex).Value = Math.Abs(CInt(dt1.Subtract(dt2).TotalDays / 30))
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

        Dim dt1 As Date = Date.Parse(DateTimePicker1.Text)
        Dim dt2 As Date = Date.Parse(DateTime.Now)
        txtTenure.Text = Math.Abs(CInt(dt1.Subtract(dt2).TotalDays / 30))
    End Sub
```

Comment: thank you but it did not work. :( i used this formula temporarily in textbox and it worked but what i need is to auto calculate it in a Datagridview Column.

    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

        Dim dt1 As Date = Date.Parse(DateTimePicker1.Text)
        Dim dt2 As Date = Date.Parse(DateTime.Now)
        txtTenure.Text = Math.Abs(CInt(dt1.Subtract(dt2).TotalDays / 30))
    End Sub

and the tenure is number of months.

Comment: Ok i have edit my answer tell me if he work for you.

Comment: it worked but i have to click each cells multiple times to show the answer.